# how to parse string value in textview typeface?

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I created simple Text view application. It's working fine, I need to parse string value in text view. because I have one XML file, my XML file contain some empty tag if I read that empty tag I need bold view in my text view ex: This is my tag `<Strong> </Strong>`If I read this tag I wish add bold view in my text view, so I am trying to add bold view in my text view.

xml file:

```
      <text>
<![CDATA[<p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">
<strong>
<span style="font-size:30px;">
<span style="font-family:georgia,serif;">
<span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">
welcome </span>
</span>
</span>

</strong>
</span></p>
]]>
                </text>
```

Code :

```
   NodeList Bold_value = tt.getElementsByTagName("strong");

            if (Bold_value.getLength() > 0) {
                //Style();
                bod = "Typeface.BOLD";
}
```

trying to add bold view in text view :

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sample);

        txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

        txt.setTypeface(null, bod);
```

this line am trying to parse that value:

```
txt.setTypeface(null, bod);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTypeFace` requires a `int` as argument (not a String).

so you can do this:

```
txt.setTypeFace(txt.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
```

or, as an alternative:

```
int bod = Typeface.NORMAL;
if (Bold_value.getLength() > 0) {
            //Style();
            bod = Typeface.BOLD;
}
txt.setTypeFace(txt.getTypeface(),bod);
```

(and keep the current typeface instead of passing null)

Comment: I have tried your second one but I am getting error  in this line why? Style.BOLD and NORMAL error : NORMAL cannot be resolved or is not a field, BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: oups... sorry my mistake. Use Typeface instead of Style (I fixed my post)

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks pretty much like html, you can use :

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(<html string>))
```